# Insert Query SQL help. Syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2015

This is the code I have

```
static public void GenerateOrder(string Time, string Date)
{
      MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; uid = root; database = coursework; password = root;");
      conn.Open();
      MessageBox.Show(Date + Time);
      string statement = ("INSERT INTO order (CustomerID, Name, Date, Time, Price) VALUES(" + Users.UserID + ",'" + Users.Firstname + "','" + Date + "','" + Time + "'," + OrderPrice + ");");
      MessageBox.Show(statement);
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(statement, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show("Order successfully placed.");
      conn.Close();
}
```

Why does it give me the Error "You have an error in your SQL Syntax"?

Please help, I have been stuck for hours
In my SQL database, CustomerID is an Int, Name, Time and Data are VARCHAR(45) and the price is a double(2,2)

Comment: Have you tested the generated SQL in SSMS?

Comment: SQL server or mysql? Cannot be both.

Comment: First add the complete error message and second use Prepared Statements

Comment: Why 2 tags? Mssql and mysql?

Comment: You need to read, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: *You have an error in your SQL Syntax* - this is MySQL.

Comment: ... `near 'order` perhaps?

Comment: This is for MySQL by the way

Comment: see the duplicate it was closed with; and look at your table name.